# How to know user permissions allow to create directory in PHP

Tags: php

**Q : How to know user permissions allow to create directory in PHP?**

---

**Case** : I want to create a directory using `mkdir()` function in PHP.

**Problem** : How do I know that I'm in admin state : able to create directory permissions using current OS.

Moreover, I want to check the permissions before using `mkdir()` function for some action trigger.

Another suggest will be appreciated.

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: @rsz i just handle the error if it can't create directory, no idea.. i'm thinking using is_write or is_read in root directory, but i think that not good idea.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to create a directory you need to be able to write to the parent directory.

So the simplest solution is to `is_writable` and `is_dir` (So you initial idea was correct). For example:

```
if(isDirWritable($baseDir)) {
    mkdir($baseDir.'/'.$dirName);
} else {
    throw new \Excpetion(sprintf('%s is not a directory or is not writable', $baseDir));
}

function isDirWritable($dir) {
  return is_dir($dir) && is_writable($dir);
}
```

You can, of course, play with the code if you want to distinguish between not directory and not writable but that should already be simple.

Comment: Why is this better, than checking the return value of `mkdir` and handle the error if necessary?

Comment: @Pred Simply because the execution flow of the code should never be driven by exceptions or errors. May not always be possible with all PHP extensions and built-in methods but in this case it is and should be preferred (IMO).

Comment: You are invoking a method each time you want to create a directory, which will do the same check you do implicitly. In this case, the more efficient way is to actually try to do the action and handle the event when it fails. This solution has no benefit, adds extra complexity and fails to check if the action is done or not. Checking all possible error sources is not efficient in this case. (IMO)

Comment: To reflect to this: `the execution flow of the code should never be driven by exceptions or errors`.  Getting a result which tells us that an external operation is done successfully does not an exception or and error. It is how the file system is intended to work (to report when it can not do something). It IS expected, that the result of such APIs are handled in the calling application. The app is not the PHP code, the API is the file system function and the API call can return true or false.

Comment: @Pred Don't get me wrong by this is getting off-topic ;) But I do agree that this may not be the best solution all the time (especially when it heavily impacts performance). I agree with your second comment to some extent. The problem is that this particular API does not only return true/false. It raises a warning. And even though you can convert it to exception it is still generic and not really helpful. And then you need to wrap all such API calls with try/catch blocks (and please don't suggest suppressing warnings). We can continue this discussion in a private conversation if you like :)

Comment: I see your point and I see, that PHP's implementation is not the best. Suppressing php warnings and notices is a bad idea, I agree with this too. A such warning is most probably an important one in any system, and as a sysadmin I would like to get them. However mkdir will only emit a warning when the directory already exists or when the permissions are not sufficient. About a chat: If you have anything to share, I will be available in about an hour.

Comment: @Pred I have to get going now but we can definitely create a chat later and will happily share some of my thoughts :)

Comment: @Pred I already created a chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112940/handling-response-internal-api-php